# Create View Controller from Nib with Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/17811/how-to-make-a-simple-mac-app-on-os-x-10-7-tutorial-part-13

But do it in Swift.

Trying to do the create master view controller step I have this code:

```
    import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var window: NSWindow
    @IBOutlet var vc: MasterViewController?

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        vc = MasterViewController(nibName: "MasterViewController", bundle: nil)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}
```

However on the MasterViewController instantiation I get the error:
Could not find an overload for '__conversion' that accepts the supplied arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a bug, because documentation says that bundle can be nil but in swift it's not allowed, throws that error.

But you can pass NSBundle.mainBundle() as bundle and it works.

Quote from NSViewController documentation:

> The bundle in which to search for the nib file. If you specify nil, this method looks for the nib file in the main bundle.

Comment: Thanks - it does compile now but the view controller doesn't load.
I check the optional result and it is nil. Perhaps another bug?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a bug xcode's autogeneration of initializers for Swift.

Since the bundle can be nil, the correct signature for an NSViewController's init is:

```
init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)
```

However, when you create a new NSViewController subclass, xcode creates an init method for you and it is given this signature:

```
init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle)
```

Notice the missing ? after NSBundle. This means that you cannot specify a nil NSBundle.

Fortunately, this is just a bug in the code autogenerator. You can either change NSBundle to NSBundle? or you can just delete the init method if you're not using it.

Comment: Thanks for that but the view controller still doesn't load. Do you have a working example project under OSX?